How to fix Invalid module name in augmentation error for express-session
I am trying to deploy my node application in Render web hosting. But each time the deployment process start, I get this error that says
error Command failed with exit code 2.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
src/@types/session.d.ts(3,16): error TS2665: Invalid module name in augmentation. Module 'express-session' resolves to an untyped module at '/opt/render/project/src/node_modules/express-session/index.js', which cannot be augmented.

I have a custom type declaring of some parameter since am using TypeScript and I can't find  a typing for them
Below is the type declaration src/@types/session.d.ts:
import session from "express-session";

declare module "express-session" {
  interface SessionData {
    userId: any;
    amount: any;
    code: any;
    historyRecords: any;
    plan: any;
    plan_id: any;
    withdrawalRecord?: any;
   
  }
}

This works perfectly well on my local machine, but upon deployment on Render, it keeps throwing the error. This is my tsConfig file
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types",
      "./@types",
     
     
    ],
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist/**/*"],
  "lib": ["es2015"],
}


I have tried everything possible but am still getting the error. I already installed type definition for "express-session" but the problem still persists. What can I try next?

This happened to me because I didn't have @types/express-session installed in my production build
